# Spring JSR303/349 validation without @Validated

Tags: java, json, spring, validation, jsonschema2pojo

I'm generating POJOs from json schema using jsonschema2pojo.  I want to use the jsr303/349 bean validation stuff.  I added the necessary items to the classpath, added the necessary beans to trigger the validation, however jsonschema2pojo does not add `@org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` to the generated classes and so the validation doesn't get triggered when a request comes into my spring boot application.

I was able to confirm that my validator is set up correctly by writing an empty class like so and changing the `@RequestBody` type to the new type:

```
@Validated
class SomeClass extends SomeGeneratedClass {

}
```

When I did so validation works as expected.  However, we're looking at dozens if not potentially a hundred or more of these extension objects and having a bunch of those is the epitome of wet (IE, not DRY) code and so this is less than ideal as a solution.

So my question is: Is there a way to trigger bean validation in spring on an incoming request if the object in question is not annotated with `@Validated`?  Note that jsonschema2pojo does not have a dependency currently on Spring and I find it unlikely the author would accept a pull request that adds one.

**-- Code if it's helpful**

An example JSON schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "userIds": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "string" },
      "minSize": 1
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["userIds"]
}
```

Generated class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "userIds"
})
public class ExampleSchema {

    /**
     * 
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("userIds")
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private List<String> userIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * 
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("userIds")
    public List<String> getUserIds() {
        return userIds;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("userIds")
    public void setUserIds(List<String> userIds) {
        this.userIds = userIds;
    }

    public ExampleSchema withUserIds(List<String> userIds) {
        this.userIds = userIds;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder().append(userIds).toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((other instanceof ExampleSchema) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        ExampleSchema rhs = ((ExampleSchema) other);
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(userIds, rhs.userIds).isEquals();
    }
}
```

Validation bean setup in my WebConfig:

```
    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator) {
        final MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator);

        return methodValidationPostProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
```

And my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void postExample(@RequestBody @Valid ExampleSchema example) {
    //Perform actions on validated object
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think '@validated' is not necesary on the object. You can use it as is in your postExample. You need to use '@valid' or '@validated' if you have properties referencing to an object that also need to be validated. In this case you need to annotate the property.

Comment: My object is not being validated unless I extend it with a class that has @Validated on it

Comment: Also you'll note in the generated class above there is already an @Valid annotation on the property

Comment: What version of Spring boot are you using ? Have you tried without the custom validator?

Comment: I'm not using a custom validator.  Spring boot 1.5.2.RELEASE

Comment: How do is the json for your example ? What is not validating ?

Comment: It's not validating any of it.  My test case is sending a null userId array (via postman).

Comment: Please add the json that you're using.

Comment: It's already up there in the question.  It's abbreviated, but it's what I'm using

Comment: I can't see the json

Comment: {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "userIds": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "string" },
      "minSize": 1
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["userIds"]
}

Comment: It's right under the "-- Code if it's helpful" bold section above

Comment: Or do you mean the json I'm sending? In this case, `{}`

Comment: I added an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class you're defining and instantiating the array in the same line.

```
private List<String> userIds = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So, when Spring validate the object, the List userIds is not null.

You have two options here.

1. You can remove the instantiation of the userIds.

   private List userIds;
2. You can change the validation. Instead of using  `@NotNull` you can use `@Size(min=1)`or you can use they both. Also you can use `@NotEmpty` but you need the hibernate validator.

Comment: ahh that makes sense.  Just have to have jsonschema2pojo not initialize collections.  Now to figure out why my minSize: 1 isn't generating the appropriate annotation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate `Controller` or `Service` with `@Validated` rather than doing it for all objects that need to be validated, as:

```
@Validated
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postExample(@RequestBody @Valid ExampleSchema example){
       //Perform actions on validated object
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried every combination of adding `@Validated` I could think of.  I tried putting it on the controller, the method, even adding it next to @Valid on the `RequestBody`, and every combination of the above.  Validation is still not triggering

Answer (score 0):

create an initbinder in your controller  like this:

```
@Autowired
YourValidator validator;

@InitBinder()
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

    binder.setValidator(validador);

}
```

And in your endpoint

```
public OrdenServicioTo guardarOrden(@ModelAttribute("dto")@Validated @RequestBody Object dto)
{
    ///YOurCode
}
```